# Android NestedScrollView is Lagging when scrolling up and down

Tags: java, android, xml, nestedscrollview

I created a viewpager with 3 fragment in a Coordinatorlayout.
Inside every Viewpager you can find a NestedScrollView with some content.
But if i scroll the content up and down its lagging.
I tested and replaced the NestedScrollView with a normal ScrollView and it was smooth. The issue is something with the nestedscrollview.
I hope for some help. Thanks.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
      app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/black"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        layout="@layout/floating_action_button_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside the viewpager you can find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
    style="@style/NestedScrollBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    tools:context="com.amirkhan.template1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sadsff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[after adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLdwN.png)

Answer (score 2):

H Amir,

please put the below line in your code

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: there is no recyclerview.

Comment: Sorry in case of recycle view use your layout

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your `LinearLayout` object in your java code:

```
linearLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
        style="@style/NestedScrollBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        tools:context="com.amirkhan.template1.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="sadsff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I get this: The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Comment: still the same message

Comment: There is no way to get the error. We only add a scroll view property in the xml right?  Please make sure it was working before the edit that i mention.

Comment: look at the image pls

Comment: Share the image

Comment: Can you please change the sdk version to 24 or less(From the end corner of preview tab) and try

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Use `<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView  ... />`

Answer (score 0):

This is the one i made and works fine.

The part that u mostly need is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="true"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

And i made this one for you, so you can try it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
<LinearLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sadsff"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```